# Prettier - custom config option

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting, prettier

how to made prettier to format my code in the way lika on a picture?

[image: code_format]

Every time I save my code it is formatted to one line of code, but it's much more readable for me to keep it like on shared picture.

EDIT:

My .prettierrc:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 200,
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "parser": "typescript",
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2
}
```

Comment: That should work, as shown in [this playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEMAWBLAzgOgEYCGANkTlnDAGpxERgYwCeAFAEwAM7ANAAQfsBKMhQBCEAK5QwcZuxwB2IeRgBhCCQwATOAHUIAJyKaxkzVmYx94uEooBlMMRlz2AFlswAsgSznWAgG4AHSgQLhAIAAcYDGgsZFACfX0IAHcABSSEeJRiVIJGePC8fQIwAGt7SLKMKABzZEtrcLQYAFsiHUx4LGrpO2yGDAA3BkZkcF8wkFryfRh00rq2gmQAM2JycIArLAAPEVKK+wI2uAAZWrh1zbgd-btauqI4AEVxCHgboi2Qav05hNCHgaNNIvpajAdFp0MgABzcP4pcg6UqRCbguBzYbXcIARw+8EWURyIB8AFooHA4NpNNN9HACRgGYsCMtVkgNj87iByG0MI0rDysE8Xu9PtdObdwjACHhoZpYUhWDLShgiE81G0VhMsQBWabicgAFTlOS5v2G1gAklBtLAHBDogBBO12Jgvb7kAC+3qAA).

Comment: What's your configuration look like?

Comment: Added my config in main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to reduce your `printWidth` in order to do this. The default of 80 will format like you want. Prettier intentionally limits its options to reduce customizability, which you can [read about here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html).

Comment: Yeah, but it's format my whole file to 80, not that single block.

Comment: Yep, that's how prettier works. There's nothing else you'll be able to do without changing your code's structure.